# AMPL logfile doesn't work

Tags: export-to-csv, ampl

When I write run file for my problem, I want to use `log_file` command, so after I load data and model, I write following option command:

1. option `solver cplex`;
2. option `omit_zero_rows 0`;
3. option `presolve 1`;
4. option `show_stats 1`;
5. option `csvdisplay_header 0`;
6. option `log_file AMPL_log.txt`;
7. option `cplex_options 'timelimit 900'`;

   `solve`;

However, when I run it on `AMPL`, the terminal shows the information

> "Error at _cmdno 6 executing "option" command can't open
> "AMPL_Log.txt" "

I don't know where I made a mistake in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `can't open <filename>` is often caused by not having permissions to write the file (or, on Windows, if the file is already opened by another application). By default AMPL creates the log file in the current working directory, but you can specify the full path to the location where you have write permissions, e.g. in your home directory:

```
option log_file '/path/to/log/file';
```